# PHP PDOException not catching

Tags: php, pdo, error-handling

I need some guidance on PDO error handling.

I got this code:

```
<?php
$config = include('config.php');

try{
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host-127.0.0.1;dbname=not_a_valid_dbname', $config->username, $config->password);
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo 'Yup!';
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Caught! '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

As you can see I provided an unvalid db name. This page outputs 'Yup!' instead of letting me know that there is no such database. Same goes when changing 'mysql:not_valid_host'. Only when I change driver name it throws an error letting me know that there is no driver by that name.

I tried:

Checking php.ini for settigs (I have hard time getting around with this)

Adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
```

Adding

```
ini_set('display_errors',true);
```

Also tried adding a backslash in catch param:

```
catch(\PDOException $e)
```

Still the same result. Help me break my code :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is very unclear, but I've made some tests and drawn some conclusions. *This is pure speculation*. I'll try to back some of these claims up if I find further information.

- If `host` is not present, `localhost` is then assumed.
- Database name is not mandatory. This is, I imagine, so you can connect to a server and create a new database through `PDO`.
- If you have a syntax error, the string will stop being considered thereafter.

With those suppositions, we can assume why your code is working the way it is. Your DSN is:

```
mysql:host-127.0.0.1;dbname=not_a_valid_dbname
```

Since there's a syntax error (`-` after `host`), neither of the parameters are considered, and there's no DB selected, with the `host` being `localhost`. This is why you get no errors. If you delete the `host` parameter, however:

```
mysql:dbname=not_a_valid_dbname
```

`localhost` is used as host (selected by default), but `not_a_valid_dbname` is tried as the database, which results in

> Caught! SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database '1234'

`mysql:not_valid_host` would be the same case as the first example. The DSN is invalid so `localhost` is assumed with no database selected.

Further, you get no error because no actual DB is selected but you didn't try to run a query. As soon as you do,

```
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:', "root", "root");
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $handler->query("SELECT * FROM test");
    echo 'Yup!';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Caught! '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

You'll get an `PDOException`, as expected:

> Caught! SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Like I said, all of this is speculation as I couldn't really find concrete evidence on most of this. I hope this guides you in the right direction. I'll keep looking for more information and edit if I find anything.